# Smallest Perfect Cube ending in 888

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Find the Smallest Perfect cube ending in 888

My Try: First of all its cube root should have Last digit as $2$.

Now if $x888$ is a Perfect Cube Then $$x888=888+1000x=8(111+125x)$$ which means $111+125x$ should be a Perfect cube.

Need a small Hint to Proceed Further

Comment: Hint: You're assuming it's a four digit number. Why? Think bigger.

Comment: Also, the cube root of $111+125x$ should have last digit $1$ (using your own logic). Hence $111+125x$ itself should have last digit $1$. Hence $x$ must be even.

Comment: @NikhilMahajan: What makes you say that?

Comment: Because it is evidently not true... You literally only have to check up to the number 21, to realize that. Which means checking the number 12.

Comment: BTW, $442^3$ ends with $888$.

Comment: The answer is 192.

Comment: @barakmanos ...and $1942^3$ ends in $88888$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already figured out the ones digit of the root is $2$.

So, the number $(10x + 2)^3 = 1000x^3 + 600x^2 + 120x + 8$ ends with $...888$.

This number modulo $10$ is obviously $8$. So, you remove the $8$ and divide by $10$. Now you got $100x^3 + 60x^2 + 12x$. This number has to end in $...88$.

Now, $100x^3 + 60x^2 + 12x \equiv 12x \,\, (\textrm{mod}\ 10)$

So, $12x$ has to end in an $8$ and thus, $x$ either ends in $4$ or $9$. So, now we've narrowed down possibilities to $x = 4, 9, 14, 19, 24 ...$ If you check these numbers, you find that $x = 19$ is the answer.

Thus, the smallest perfect cube to end in 888 is 192. (Remember the root is $10x + 2$)

---

EDIT: If you want to do a bit more work, you can figure out the following:

$60x^2$ will always end in $...60$ for $x$ that ends in $4$ or $9$. (If it isn't immediately obvious, work at it a bit more).

Which means that, $12x$ must end in $...28$ to get the desired $...88$ - this narrows down to ALL numbers whose cubes end in $...888$, which are $19,44,69,94$.

Here, an interesting pattern emerges.

**All numbers of the form $250x + 192$ (where $x$ is a non-negative integer) are roots of perfect cubes ending in $...888$.**

Comment: You mean "all numbers of the form $10(19+25x)+2$, surely?

Comment: Ah, yes - you are right. I mixed them up.

Answer (score 1):

From where you left it:
$$a^3\equiv 111\equiv -14\pmod{125}$$

This implies:
$$a^3\equiv 11\pmod{25}$$

You have $4^3\equiv14\equiv-11\pmod{25}$, so $a\equiv -4\equiv 21\pmod{25}$.

Trying possible values of $a$ (21,46,71,96,141) with a calculator, you can find $96^3\equiv 111\pmod{125}$ and $192^3=7077888$.

Comment: This implicitly uses the fact that cube roots are unique in $\mathbb Z_{25}^\times$, which might not be very obvious at this level.

Answer (score 0):

I would continue digit by digit. You know that the ones digit of the root is `2`.

Now try all possible tens digits and find out which one(s) yield the a cube whose *last* two digits are `88`.

For each of your solutions, then, try all possible hundreds digits.

Now you have all three-digit numbers whose cube is 888 modulo 1000. Take the smallest of those and cube it.