# To find smallest $n$ such that $2^{n} \equiv 111 \pmod{125} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> How to find the smallest natural number $n$ such that $2^{n} \equiv 111 \pmod{125} $.

If we consider $\pmod{5}$ then $2^n \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$. For $n=4k+l$ where $l \in \left\{ 0, 1, 2, 3\right\}$ we get $16^k 2^l \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ and $2^l \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, which leads to $l=0$. Therefore, equation reduces to $16^k \equiv 111 \pmod{125}$.

What to do next?

Comment: Sage says $n=36$

Comment: I think $2^n\equiv 111\equiv -14\pmod{125}$ implies that $2^n\equiv 11\pmod{25}$

Comment: Maybe, similar implicity used here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133616/smallest-perfect-cube-ending-in-888

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 That questions solves $n^3\equiv888\pmod{1000}$, which is quite a different question.

Comment: @Servaes, I  shared it because of answers ajotatxe.

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 I see now, that is a bit more related indeed. Did you know that you can also link to answers by means of the 'share' button at the bottom of the answer?

Comment: @Servaes, I am a novice in this site. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next solve $16^k\equiv11\pmod{25}$, which yields $k\equiv4\pmod{5}$. Set $k=5m+4$ so that
$$16^k\equiv16^4\times(16^5)^m\equiv36\times76^m\pmod{125}.$$
Because $36\times66\equiv1\pmod{125}$ we now want to solve
$$76^m\equiv66\times111\equiv76\pmod{125},$$
which shows that $m=1$ will do, corresponding to $n=36$.

Answer (score 1):

By Hensel's lifting lemma we have that $2$ is a generator for $\mathbb{Z}/(5^3\mathbb{Z})^*$, hence this is a job for the discrete logarithm machinery. We may pre-compute $2^{0},2^{11},2^{22},\ldots,2^{121}\pmod{125}$ and $2^{0},2^{1},2^{2},\ldots,2^{10}\pmod{125}$, then perform a simple scan (this is the baby step-giant step approach).  Since
$$ 2^{33}\cdot 2^{3} \equiv 92\cdot 8 \equiv 111\pmod{125}$$
the answer is given by $33+3=\color{red}{36}$.